# Avoid CSS animations to leave the viewport

Tags: css, html, position

I'm trying to set up a web design with tiles, which shall zoom out on hover. It basically works fine. But tiles at the edge of the screen obviously extend beyond the viewport. Is there any way to solve this without JavaScript?

```css
#tiles article {
    width: 150px;
    height: 225px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#tiles div.growingtile {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 225px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2 ease-in-out;
}
#tiles div.growingtile:hover {
    z-index: 100;
    left: -75px;
    top: -10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section id="tiles">
  <article>
    <div class="growingtile">
      <p>This is just a demo text.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="growingtile">
      <p>This is another demo text.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

For the example imagine a gallery of tiles extending over multiple lines. All middle tiles behave exactly as I want them to. The leftmost tile however should not change its left value. While this is simple for the very first tile, I'm searching for a solution for **every** leftmost and probably rightmost tile.

If there is no CSS only solution. The simplest solution I currently imagine is adding a hover handler to all tiles, which tunes the tile displacement when needed. I'd also welcome any simpler ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I can definitely get it to work for your first child by using the `:first-child` psuedo-class.

You can also add the ability for `:last-child` or `:nth-child()`.

```css
#tiles article {
  width: 150px;
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#tiles div.growingtile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 225px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2 ease-in-out;
}
#tiles div.growingtile:hover {
  z-index: 100;
  left: -75px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 320px;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#tiles article:first-child div.growingtile:hover {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="tiles">
  <article>
    <div class="growingtile">
      <p>This is just a demo text.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="growingtile">
      <p>This is another demo text.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the simple part. The hard part is to figure out, which children it would affect. On a 320px width it would every odd child would be leftmost. On 768px width it would be every 5th!

Comment: The idea is to take less rows on wider screens. So dynamic widths are not intended. I thought about media queries, but it would require roughly a dozen. But yes, it seems it's the only clean pure CSS way. I'll probably stick with a dozen lines of jQuery, which does the trick. Users w/o JS will have trouble accessing the outermost tiles. Seems have to live with that.